# How to write multiple Mats within the same element name in an XML file?

Tags: xml, visual-c++, opencv, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I have 85 26*7 binary images that will be used to train a system. Im trying to write each Mat of these images one after the other in XML,all within the same element name *Training_set* as such:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<Training_set type_id="opencv-matrix">
     Mat1 values
     Mat2 values
     Mat3 values
     ......
     Mat85 values
</Training_set >
</opencv_storage>
```

Using the following code:-

```
FileStorage fs("Samples.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);

// Check if we actually created the file
if(fs.isOpened())
{ 
        IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("eye1.bmp");
        Mat imgg=cvarrToMat(img);
        fs <<"Training_set"<< imgg;

        IplImage *img2 = cvLoadImage("eye2.bmp");
        Mat imgg2=cvarrToMat(img2);
        fs <<"Trainging_set"<<imgg2;

}
```

Currently ,I obtained:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <opencv_storage>
    <Training_set type_id="opencv-matrix">
         Mat1 values
    </Training_set >
   <Training_set type_id="opencv-matrix">
         Mat2 values
    </Training_set >
    </opencv_storage>
```

As you can see they are being assigned to the same element name but *separately*.This is not what I want to achieve.How can I write all Mat values in a *single batch* within the same element name.

This XML will contain the training sample set for the neural network,developed in Opencv using Visual Studio C++.

Comment: The output stored in the XML file should be similar to the one seen in   https://raw.github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/master/Chapter5_NumberPlateRecognition/OCR.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frames are merged together and then written to the XML file.Refer to link http://devblog.michalski.im/2012/05/18/combine-multiple-video-frames-into-one-using-opencv/

First we create a Mat which stores all the images ,here I called it Merged_frame.

```
Mat Merged_frame =Mat(Size(26,595), CV_8UC3);
```

The size of Merged_frame is dependent on the size of my images used for training and the number of images.My x=26 because the images are 26*7 ...26 cols and 7 rows.We are storing 85 images vertically one after the other hence the rows will be 7*85.

The code snippet I developed to merge my images is as follows:-

```
 IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("X1.bmp");
 Mat im=cvarrToMat(img);
 roi = Mat(Merged_frame, Rect(0,0,26,7)); //Sets region of interest
 im.copyTo(roi);
```

I did this for each image,remember to change Rect(x,y,width,height) parameters accordingly.This will store the image in a specific location found in Merged_frame.

After each image is stored ,we can send Merged_frame to the XML file.

I achieved the result I needed and hope that this helps image processing newbies like myself. :) gudluk!!!